# Configuring SQL Report Server to work with Team Foundation Server using Internet URLs

Tags: sql-server, team-foundation-server, ssrs

Currently we have SQL 2012 with Reporting Services, Team Foundation Server 2012 and SharePoint Server 2013 on our single Windows Server 2012 machine. We are a small company and we have some developers who work from home. We do not have VPN nor domain controllers yet.

We wanted to expose our TFS Agile reports through Sharepoint using Windows authentication.

We created a subdomain, configured Sharepoint Alternate Access Mapping and now our devs are able to open our project web site (created automatically by TFS) from the Internet after they enter their Windows credentials.

The only problem is that our TFS Agile Dashboard on Sharepoint fails to render reports. The Web browser shows a standard error page because it is trying to access our internal URL for report server.

So we went to the report server config and added our external subdomain for both Report Web Service and Report Manager. Now we are able to access them both from external computers through Internet Explorer.

The problem is that we cannot access report server when we configure TFS Reporting settings.
TFS correctly pulls new public URLs for both Web service and Report Manager. Everything works fine if we select the public URL for Report Manager and hit OK, so TFS is able to access the Report Manager without any issues. But when we pick the public URL for Web service and hit OK, TFS asks for credentials (we tried to enter the server Admin credentials to be sure) and then fails with a message:

```
The server you specified was not found or cannot reached. 
The specified configuration is invalid. Update the fields as indicated for each tab.
```

Essentially, /Reports folder is working and can be assigned on TFS, but only /ReportServer fails.

Also, we are not able to access any of our reports nor Sharepoint sites on the server itself when entering our public URL - it asks for credentials three times and then dies. I guess, maybe that's because of some IE settings on the server, because from our other computers we are able to open all these web sites on IE right after we enter our credentials one time.

What's wrong with TFS and Reports Web Service? How do I connect them both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long long search, I found this one:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926642
It seems, Microsoft has deliberately blocked loopback authentications. That's why I cannot configure my TFS and Sharepoint URLs as needed - they just fail to authenticate.